# useLazyQuery not working inside loop and promise.all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

I've got an array of data(consist of date), and need to run a graphql query for every date inside it.
Promise resolved for every date inside the array should return new data and I want to push it in the local state of react component.

But somehow, the function is only returning data for the last element of an array.

```
    ...
    const [
        getInvoiceByDateQuery,
        { loading: getInvoiceByDateQueryLoading, data: getInvoiceByDateQueryData },
      ] = useLazyQuery(GET_INVOICES_BY_DATA, {
        onCompleted({ getInvoicesByDate }) {
          console.log({ getInvoicesByDate });
          const invoiceList = [...state.invoiceList];
          invoiceList.push(getInvoicesByDate[0]);
          _setState({
            invoiceList,
          });
        },
      });
    
    ...
    
    useEffect(async () => {
    if (!!state.currentWeek.length) {
      await Promise.all(
        state.currentWeek.map(day => {
          console.log(day);
          return getInvoiceByDateQuery({
            variables: {
              date: day,
            },
          });
        }),
      );
    }
  }, []);
```

I went through graphql documentation, it says `useLazyQuery` doesn’t return any promise like `useMutation` too.
So, inside my `useEffect` hook Promise.all is always going to return `void`.

I'm hoping to use `onCompleted` return callback of `useLazyQuery` and update the local state.

I tried using console inside map iterator, it's printing the date in console successfully for every element inside array but somehow function is only running for the last element.

Even checking the networks tab, I see the query runs only a single time.

I tried the following code too, but nothing is working -

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!!state.currentWeek.length) {
      state.currentWeek.map(day =>
        getInvoiceByDateQuery({
          variables: {
            date: day,
          },
        }),
      );
    }
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Every Apollo hook creates one 'instance', were designed to provide one operation ('data-slots') at a time.

> ... should return new data and I want to push it in the local state of react component.

Usually [and probably in this use case, too] **there is no need to copy data into the state** (data duplication).

In React you should think about **many `<Day/>` components, each reading data for itself**, rendering day-related data, providing a link to day-details page/view/etc.

Of course, **each `<Day/>` component can return fetched data to the parent**, simply render it with some handler fn (and id/index props) called in `onCompleted`.

Comment: I don't need fetched data to render, else I would’ve created a new component for that.
From the fetched data, I just need to check some conditions.

Comment: you can render nulls, componsnts are a cheap abstractions in react ...  **what conditions exactly?** maybe not realy needed in this view? ... should be provided by API ? ... if important - 30 requests for some checks looks like BAD API design ... all looks like some workaround ... why data not available at 'month' of 'data range' request? consult your API devs

Comment: at the first instance, this API can look bad, but in the backend for a single date sent as a payload, it has to be evaluated within a certain date range.

Ideally comparing the date range from another date range is not feasible.
So, either I need to make 7 calls for 7 different dates simultaneously by just changing the date in the payload or in the backend 7 times comparison should be done to check whether that date lies in any range or not.

Anyway, I've solved this thing. Will be posting the solution soon.

Comment: usually this is one continuous range (week/month/whatever) and results can be [easily] groupped [to day 'slots'] after fetching from DB, before return or even on FE (filter/reduce/etc)

Answer (score 1):

Can be solved by useApolloClient as that will allow multiple queries being fired at once.

```
const client = useApolloClient();
client.query({
        query: GET_DOG_PHOTO,
        variables: { breed: 'bulldog' },
      });
```

Comment: `useLazyQuery` is not working with `Promise.all`, it takes the last argument! and making only 1 GraphQL request.
It took me more than 2 hours to find this answer, thank you!